How do you pronounce 스퀄?
A good answer will be one of the following:


a link to an internet video.

a link to an audio file on the Wikipedia commons.

a transliteration written in international phonetic alphabet notation.




IPA: [sʰɯkʰwʌ̹ɭ] or [sʰɯkʰwɘːɭ] (where /ʌː/ = [ɘː])
(Most speakers in both Koreas no longer distinguish vowel length, so [sʰɯkʰwʌ̹ɭ] is more likely. See also this article.)
(You should also not assume that you know how to pronounce [ʌ] if you are native English speaker. Many English dictionaries traditionally continue to use "ʌ" symbol, but that vowel has actually changed to [ɐ], [ä], [ɜ] or something similar in most dialects of English. E.g. in Conservative RP /ʌ/ is pronounced as [ɐ]. See this.)
